# selectively moving partially matched files to different directories

Tags: linux, text-processing, files, mv

I am working in a Linux server where a parent directory has 100s of partially numbered files, e.g

```
GGG12345_abb.txt 
GGG12346_abc.txt 
GGG12347_cbx.txt 
.
.
GGG19045_jha.txt
```

each of which is corresponds to a one of the categories, such as:

```
myname1 
myname2
.
.
myname12
```

In addition, there is an index text file which has two columns, name and id, having partial `myname*` and `GGG` index (without `_xxx.txt`)

```
12_12_myname1_abc GGG12345
12_15_myname1_abc GGG12346
.
.
11_15_myname2_abc GGG12353
```

I have created subdirectories `MYNAME1`, `MYNAME2` etc. How can I select the files index from the index file and move corresponding text files to related subdirectoies? e.g. `GGG12345_abb.txt` of category `myname1` to directory `MYNAME1`

Comment: What do you mean under `metadata text files`? How you can receive it altogether with `category`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have updated the text. I hope it make more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If this in your metadata file:

```
12_12_myname1_abc GGG12345
```

means that you have to copy file GGG12345_**abc**.txt in directory **MYNAME1** you can parse metadata file and copy files with awk:

```
awk '{ x = split($1, arr, "_"); arr[3] = toupper(arr[3]); s = "mv " $2 "_" arr[4] ".txt " arr[3]; } { system(s); }' metadata
```

You can first test it without using `system` to see what command will do:

```
awk '{ x = split($1, arr, "_"); arr[3] = toupper(arr[3]); s = "mv " $2 "_" arr[4] ".txt " arr[3]; } { print s; }' metadata
```

If abc in:

```
12_12_myname1_abc GGG12345
```

does not matter, e.g you just need only GGG12345 and MYNAME1:

```
awk '{ x = split($1, arr, "_"); arr[3] = toupper(arr[3]); s = "mv " $2 "* " arr[3]; } { system(s); }' metadata
```

and again first you can test without using `system`:

```
awk '{ x = split($1, arr, "_"); arr[3] = toupper(arr[3]); s = "mv " $2 "* " arr[3]; } { print s; } ' metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if below script will do what you want

```
while IFS="[ _]" read a b dir c file ; do echo mv -t ${dir^^} ${file}* ; done < index.file
```

then remove `echo`.